# Cocoapods not installing latest version of FBSDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have installed FBSDK in my swift project. As I checked on GitHub the latest version of
facebook-ios-sdk is 9.1.0, but when I installed it showed 5.15.1.[image: Terminal log]

In my pod file:
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have another dependency on this library which needs this "5.15.1" version. If there isn't any: [follow this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrade-guide/)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to update cocoapods?

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```